# R converts to numeric when sorting (arrange)

Tags: r, string, vector, type-conversion, numeric

How can I stop R from converting strings to numeric while sorting a **character vector** of numbers? example using `dplyr` `arrange()`:

```
nomenclature <- read_csv2(file('~/nomenclature.txt', encoding="UTF-8"))

head(nomenclature$NOMENCLATURE)
[1] "8414900090" "6108320000" "8517709000" "6104430000" "4202310090" "8479908099"

nomenclature <- nomenclature %>% arrange(NOMENCLATURE)

head(nomenclature$NOMENCLATURE)
[1] "1.52e+09"   "1.801e+09"  "1.804e+09"  "1.805e+09"  "1001190030" "1001990094"
```

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you want, but you could try `nomenclature <- nomenclature %>% arrange(as.character(NOMENCLATURE))`. I haven't tested this, but it's similar to problems I've had in the past. Is there a reason I can't first convert your character strings to numeric?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? I can't reproduce with `nomenclature<-data.frame(NOMECLATURE=c("8414900090","6108320000","8517709000","6104430000","4202310090","8479908099"));nomenclature %>% arrange(NOMECLATURE)`

Comment: I would guess those values are actually in there before the `arrange()`

Comment: @MrFlick, you're right ! the values were actually there before. My apologies. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to MrFlick second comment: the "e+" values were actually there before the `arrange()`